# Testing an R application deployed in Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app that works locally even as a shiny app. However when I deploy it in a Shiny Server(free) running on RedHat 5 within my organization, there are strange issues with `gsub`. To debug this, I would like to see the data at different instances in the shiny code. So, is there something like `console.log` as in javascript?

I checked the documentations like the one here http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html, but they talk only about a shiny app running within RStudio which is not my case.

Note:
 1. The code that I want to use is not within the server function of the shiny app.
 2. I cannot install new packages, because of IT restrictions
 3. I don't have access to shiny server logs

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: Have you tried just using developer tools in Chrome and looking at the console? Sometimes Shiny will output code errors in the console by default if your app crashes. Getting access to the server logs (ask someone in your IT dept to send you copies) will likely be much faster than you writing debugging code. You could also use the sink() function to send some text to a log file of your choosing, but that'll be more time consuming.

Comment: Chrome console logs were not that helpful. I finally ended writing out the variables I needed to debug to an external file via, write.table(). I would be great if we could write our own console logs from shiny to chrome.

Comment: check out shinyjs. It has a logjs() function that writes messages to the console! Sounds like the perfect tool for you.